# Sum of all possible pairs of elements in an array

Tags: arrays, algorithm

I was trying to solve problem, where an array of integers is given, I need to find sum of all possible pairs of elements in an given array. 
For example  array is 1,2,3,4 
then it should give 1+2 + 1+3 + 1+4 + 2+3 + 2+4 + 3+4 = 30

Now, I tried different things but I can not come with any algorithm having complexity less than O(n^2). Does anybody have an idea about a algorithm with complexity less than O(n^2)

Comment: I don't know how this question has to do with programming, try math.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Chiel it is a programming question, I am writing java program but I thought there must be some algorithm behind it which can solve it in less than O(n^2) time.

Comment: For a solution that isn't O(n^2) there will need to be additional constraints (ie. the elements in the array are contiguous integers etc.)?

Comment: @SnOrfus .. No ,there is no other constraint .. look at G. Bach answer, it perfectly gives the answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since every element of the array occurs in exactly `n-1` pairs, sum all of them up and multiply by `n-1`, which means this is `O(n)`.

---

This actually generalizes to the case where you need the sum of the sums of all k-element multisets. In that case, every element of the array appears in exactly `(n-1) choose (k-1)` multisets, so add them all up and multiply by that. The calculation of the binomial coefficient may become a bit much at some point, but definitely beats enumerating all k-element multisets and adding them up.

Answer (score -1):

Unless you know something about the values in the array, I don't see any way to do it that isn't O(n^2).

The number of combinations of N items taken 2 at a time is:

```
N           C
10          45
100       4950
1000    499500
```

As you can see, the number of combinations is approximately (N^2)/2 so I don't see how you can do better than that without extra information.

Answer (score -1):

In c++ there is a function called `next_permutation()` which generates next 'combination' of elements in array. So you can do something like this:

```
int A=[1,2,3,4,5];
while(next_permutation(A,A+5)) //NOTE: A is pointer to first element of array A
{
    // do something
}
```

If you get the idea, you should be able to customize code for your problem.