# Difference of all possible pairs of numbers in an array

Tags: arrays, algorithm, difference

Suppose I have a reverse-sorted list of doubles: `{3, 2, 1}`

I want to find the sum of all the positive differences between possible pairs of numbers.
In this case, that would be `(3-2)+(3-1)+(2-1) = 4`.

I know that going through all the pairs is an option, but this takes O(n^2) time. Any idea on a better algorithm?

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28596059/sum-of-all-possible-pairs-of-elements-in-an-array) is a very similar question that's been answered, but I can't quite find how to apply this to differences instead of sums.

Comment: Forget coding for a second.  This is a counting exercise.  Hint:  how may +3's will there be in that sum?  How many +2's?    How many -2's?  How many -1's?  Can you think of a way If you know there are n 3's, then that's 3n.  Are there just as many +3's as there are -1's?  That's interesting, right?  Spend some time soaking in the beauty of the symmetry of this sum.

Comment: @derpirscher Yep, sorry for the typo

Comment: I don't see how you can make it faster. But how many elements will this array have and how many times do you need to compute these sums?

Comment: @Wyck I think I understand. The twos cancel out and leave 2*3-2*1, and the general solution for array V would be (n-1)*V[0]+(n-3)*V[1]+...+(-n+1)*V[n-1]. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `i`-th element (with `i = 0 .. n-1`) in your sorted list will be

- added to the sum `n-i-1` times
- substracted from the sum `i` times

So you can simply do

```
let sum = 0;
for (let i = 0; i < n; i++)
  sum = sum + (n-i-1) * list[i] - i * list[i]
```

Comment: This explains the process. Besides that, the equation can be shortened to: `sum += (n - 1 - 2*i) * list[i];`

Comment: @Thomas Yes, the math can be simplified. But I decided to keep the original formula which expresses the addtions and substractions better ...